# Adding 4M embeddings to Faiss Index

Tags: python, numpy, faiss

I'm learning `Faiss` and trying to build an `IndexFlatIP`  quantizer for an `IndexIVFFlat` index with `4000000` arrays with `d = 256`.

My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import faiss

d = 256 # Dimension of each feature vector
n = 4000000 # Number of vectors
cells = 100 # Number of Voronoi cells

embeddings = np.random.rand(n, d)

quantizer = faiss.IndexFlatIP(d)
index = faiss.IndexIVFFlat(quantizer, d, cells)
index.train(embeddings) # Train the index
```

The code above works great, but when it comes to adding the embeddings to the index:

`index.add(embeddings)`

I get the following exception:

```
numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 4.01 GiB for an array with shape (4000000, 256) and data type float32
```

Seeing as this is a `numpy` memory error, does it mean my index does not fit in memory? The machine I am using has 20.0GB. If so, how can I work around this issue and correctly configure my index so that it fits into memory?

Comment: 4.01 GB seems suspiciously like a 32-bit limit. You can try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22896826/17200348) if an array <4 GB _does_ work.

Comment: I have just double-checked that my Python is running as 64-bit with cmd: `python -c "import sys; print(sys.maxsize > 2**32)"`

Comment: It's not about Python, but about NumPy. Have you checked the solution I linked?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add: I have also checked that my `numpy` distribution (1.23.5) is running on 64 bits.
`import numpy.distutils.system_info
print(sysinfo.platform_bits)`

Comment: It might be worth a shot checking the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type).

Comment: Indeed, it was a memory overcommitment problem which I could only solve by manually increasing the dynamic pagefile size.