# Limit Python Memory Resources on osX / VirtualEnv like php.ini memory_limit

Tags: python, macos, memory-management, virtualenv

Need to replicate limited memory on hosting account. In php it's a simple as setting memory_limit in the `php.ini` config file.

Using `VirtualEnv`, and not finding any reference to `memory` in its docs.

I've seen coding [Solutions for Linux and Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760025/limit-python-vm-memory), but they aren't working on osX (maybe they would with XTools).

The following script on Unix returns the expected `MemoryError` on `Linux`, but on `osX 10.6.8` it just runs Python resources above `2GB` ('till ended via the osX Activity Monitor as KeyboardInterrupt doesn't seem to do it).

```
import resource

"""
python break_resources.py
"""

for n in range(0, 1000000000):
    n = n * 100000000000

resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_CORE, (1, 100))
```

Experimenting with `multiprocessing` so there may be certain solutions which will not work in this case.

Comment: It doesn’t seem to be possible to do this easily on the mac: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274385/how-to-limit-memory-of-a-os-x-program-ulimit-v-neither-m-are-working#comment4987496_3276945